# How to test @Async Spring methods with junit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-async

I have an `@Async` method and want to test it with `junit`.
Problem: I want junit to fire all calls to the async method without blocking, so don't want for the outcome.

But in my following example, each call first waits for the async method to return, and then continue with the next incovation:

```
@Service
public class MainService {
    @Autowired
    private SubService sub;
    
    @Async
    public void processAsync() {
        sub.run();
    }
}


@SpringBootTest
public class MainServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private MainService service;

    @MockBean
    private SubService sub;
    
    @Test
    public void testAsync() {
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(5);
    
        when(sub.run()).then((answer) -> {
            latch.countDown();
            latch.await(); //return when latch is 0
            return;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
            //TODO this currently runs in sync. why?
            service.processAsync();
        }
    }   
}
```

I want all service calls to block until latch count reaches 0, and then continue the test.

But what I get is that the `SubService` is only called once, and then stucks inside the mocked `Answer` method.

Question: why are my `service.process()` calls inside the `@Test` method not fired 5x directly?

Answer (score 1):

The follow clue is to let sub-method wait for a `CountDownLatch`. This way, all threads will first be started and wait inside the subroutine.

Then, inside the test method, release the latch, so that all methods continue:

```
@Test
public void testAsync() {
        CountDownLatch waiter = new CountDownLatch(1);
        
        when(sub.run()).then((answer) -> {
            waiter.await();
            return;
        }
        
        Stream.generate(() -> new Thread(() -> service.processAsync()))
                .limit(6)
                .forEach(Thread::start);

        waiter.countDown(); //resumes all waiting threads
}
```